# How to authorize ActiveAdmin resources with Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan, pundit

With `CanCan`, the `load_and_authorize_resource` helper method could be called in a global `before_filter` (in the `application_controller`). This would ensure that all ActiveAdmin controller actions too got authorized inherently.

But with `Pundit`, there is no such `load_and_authorize_resource` helper method. All Pundit docs and tutorials talk about calling `authorize` in every action. I am fine with calling authorize in every action. But in ActiveAdmin, the actions are not exposed by default. Am I supposed to open every action in every controller, and call `authorize` and then call `super`?

This seems wrong. So, could someone please tell me how to use Pundit to authorize the actions in ActiveAdmin?

**Update**:

I know about the Pundit authorization adapter. I am using the master branch of AA and I have configured AA to use the Pundit adapter, as described [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md). My question is: how do I make use of the adapter? By just setting `config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter`, does it automatically invoke the authorization of every action in ActiveAdmin? I don't think so.

For example, in CanCan, even after setting `config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter`, you still have to set `load_and_authorize_resource` as a global before_filter for it to authorize all AA actions automatically.

Comment: For me it was very easy. I've included Pundit module to ApplicationController, added PunditAdapter to the ActiveAdmin config and created Policies for all the models. And it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveAdmin's master now includes a Pundit authorization adapter. If you are using the master branch of ActiveAdmin, Pundit can be easily utilized. Otherwise you can manually add the existing [pundit_adapter.rb](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/pundit_adapter.rb) to older versions of ActiveAdmin, although more work might be required.

See [ActiveAdmin PR #2857](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2857) for more context and detail on how the adapter was added.

---

After ActiveAdmin is setup to use the Pundit authorization adapter, it does check the authorization for the default resource actions: show, index, edit, update, new, create, destroy. Any custom actions must be manually authorized.

One detail to check is that your Pundit policy defines the methods expected by ActiveAdmin. There is a [template](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/lib/generators/pundit/install/templates/application_policy.rb) available to be used as a starting point. The ActiveAdmin [authorization docs](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md) may also be helpful.

Comment: I have already set the Pundit adapter as my authorization adapter. I have updated the question to add more info.

Comment: ActiveAdmin does authorize the default resource and page actions. Do you have an example? Could you be more specific about the issue?

Comment: I just tried a totally vanilla sample app with only activeadmin, pundit and one model. The authorization seemed to work all fine. So, I guess the problem I faced is something to do within my app. Need to check what it is.